# I want a specific page two (backside of page 1)

Tags: floats, xetex, page-breaking

I want to generate an invoice (with address-window) with a longtable (or tabularx or csvauto), so the content may fill more than one page.

What I want to achieve - and have no idea how to adress the problem - is, that I want to have some explaining Texts (some legal thingies) on the second page (with nothing else on it) (doublesided output).

I could use some pstricks to move a second page (separately generated) behind the first, but than page-numbering and page-referencing are not possible. (f.e. I use the referencing feature to tweak the "legal matter page" to display only necessary information)

I tried with floating figures (option p), but that moves the special page to the end.

Any ideas?

Comment: So, you want your invoice on pages 1 and 3, and legal matter on page 2? I'd try generating the invoice and the legal matter each to its own pdf, then combine the pages in a third document with pdfpages. You may have to fudge the page sizes a bit for it to fit.

Comment: and how do I address the problem with page-numbering and forward page references?

Comment: The legal stuff should not be part of the numbering. What you want is a oneside document. The legal stuff on the back is usually preprinted.

Comment: thanks Johannes, but here I have a different approach, as the legal matter  has f.e. an "expiry date" printed depending on invoice-items

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following might fit your requirements: using the package `atbegshi` the pagenumber is increased when it is 1 (this is page 2, I'm not really sure when the automatic increase of the page counter occurs exactly). The legal matter is put at the end of the document, but the page number is set to 2. Page references seem to work properly using this approach. When the pdf is created, you can shift the pages around with `pdftk` or similar external tools, or even just print the document with a different page order.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{atbegshi}

\AtBeginShipout{
    \ifnum\value{page}=1
        \addtocounter{page}{1}
    \fi
}

\begin{document}
\section{Invoice}
\label{sec:invone}
See Section \ref{sec:invtwo} on page \pageref{sec:invtwo}.

\noindent See also Section \ref{sec:invthree} on page \pageref{sec:invthree}.
\clearpage
\section{Invoice continued}
\label{sec:invtwo}
\clearpage
\section{Invoice again continued}
\label{sec:invthree}
\clearpage
\setcounter{page}{2}
\section{Legal matter}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I will adapt this approach. Maybe I  can replace "addtocounter" with my hole page including \newpage.

Comment: That might work indeed - however I'm not sure how the shipout process behaves if pages are added. Let us know what you find :)